# Is it possible to submit a MathJobs application before a reference letter arrives?

Tags: mathematics, application

If I'm awaiting a reference letter, is it possible to send a MathJob application before the reference letter arrives? If I do this, will the employer be able get that reference letter whenever it is uploaded? Or should I not do this because the application would be submitted without the required letter?

Comment: If you expect the reference letter to be available soon then you might put off submitting your application through mathjobs.org until the application deadline.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I personally wouldn't recommend this.  Many faculty look at applications early, so those applications have a chance to build up some momentum.  Most people I've talked to about this agree it's better to apply early.  Though perhaps this depends some on how the department does things.

Comment: Having chaired four search committees in the last 10 years I've had experience of this.  In my experience, it doesn't matter when you apply, since committees typically don't look at applicants much until after the deadline.  In any case, there's a trade-off between having your application in early without a reference letter (which might influence how the application is read) or waiting and having a more complete application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. (At any rate, it was a few years ago -- I assume the software has not changed since then.) Hiring committees will be able to see whatever you have submitted, and once your reference writer submits your letter it will be visible with the rest of your application.

Comment: It is still possible now.

Comment: Note however that if the committee downloads (or even prints out!) the applications then the late-arriving reference letter may not be seen by committee members.  This is one reason that it is best for committee members to work with applications in the mathjobs system rather than downloading them.